# How to make a video responsive using the Media:vimeo and Media:youtube modules

Tags: 7, media

How to make a video responsive using the Media:vimeo and Media:youtube modules?

I read somewhere to add some css:

```
.file-video-vimeo{
  padding-top:56.25%; /*16:9 aspect ratio*/
  position:relative;
}

.media-vimeo-video{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

..and to set both width and height to 100% in the video display settings.

However, this does not work for me, it does not show full width of its container.

I see in my page html that for the vimeo player,
vp-player-layout js-playerLayout 
has

```
left: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
```

Why is this? This causes the video not to be the full width.

[image]

Comment: Add `.vp-player-layout .js-playerLayout { left: initial !important; right: initial !important; }`

Comment: @No Sssweat: your solution makes the video disappear completely. By the way, if I try left:0 and right:0, it becomes full-width allright but the top and bottom are cut off a bit. Another fact that might influence this issue is that the video is a screenrecording of non-standard dimensions (1440x900)

Comment: @Yuri `full-width allright but the top and bottom are cut off a bit` I think that explains why they did the `left: 40; right: 40;`

Comment: Hm..I can't figure out the right way to get automatic height. width works at 100% but not auto-height. I give up...installed fitvids that works out of the box.